# Get raw data for timeseries autocorrelation function (plot_acf)

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

It's easy to plot acf however I didn't find anywhere a way to extract raw values.

How can I access correlation coefficient and statistical significate by lag index?

Kind of:
x[1] -> (1,NaN)
or
x[12] -> (0.9,0.21)

[image]

Comment: You can use [statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html).

Comment: Works as a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What would you like to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Flavia posted in the comment section the answer is to use: [statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html).

Answering to be able to mark it as a proper answer in case somebody else will need it.